# Why should we preferably use first class collections?

Tags: object-oriented, generics

As per rule number 4 of [Object Calisthenics by Jeff Bay](http://www.xpteam.com/jeff/writings/objectcalisthenics.rtf) <sup>(RTF)</sup> in The ThoughtWorks Anthology, it is recommended that one should "**Use first-class collections**".

> **Rule 4: First class collections**
>
> Application of this rule is simple:
> any class that contains a collection should contain no other member
> variables.   Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now
> behaviors related to the collection have a home.  You may find that
> filters become a part of this new class.   Also, your new class can
> handle activities like joining two groups together or applying a rule
> to each element of the group.

What I could understand from this was that we should use a separate class wrapping up the collection and with methods to add,delete modify data of that collection.

and We need this so that we are sure of what datatype goes into the collection and what comes out.

In case we use generic collection (in languages where it is applicable), do we need to follow this rule?

If I am missing an important significance, please clarify.

Comment: Amogh Talpallikar I've changed rule 8 to rule 4, as rule 8 is actually "No classes with more than two instance variables".

Comment: It seems to say _Rule 8_ in the table of contents, and then call it _Rule 4_ in the body.

Comment: Better link http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf ?

Comment: Is it just me, or is this rule un-implementable as written? I mean, you've got a class with a collection in it, so you take everything else out. Now your class is a collection. So if you've got another class, with that class in it, it has a collection in it, and... lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @mjfgates: hmm...Great point! something to really think about!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type safety is a very minor reason to use first-class collections.  From your link:

> Rule 4: First class collections
>   Application of this rule is simple: any class that contains a collection should contain no other member variables.   Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to the collection have a home.  You may find that filters become a part of this new class.   Also, your new class can handle activities like joining two groups together or applying a rule to each element of the group.

The idea here is if you find yourself searching, filtering, validating, or anything beyond add/remove/iterate semantics on a collection, the code is asking you to put it in its own class.  If you need to update just one value (after a search), that probably goes in the collection class.

The reasoning for this is pretty simple, collections tend to get passed around.  Soon enough, 4 different classes have their own `SearchByID()` method.  Or you get return values like `Map<Integer, String>` with the context of what's stored in that map stripped away.  A first-class collection is a simple solution that costs a single source file.  In practice, once those are in place (they're very easy to write unit tests for as well), any change dealing with the collection is easy to handle, like when `SearchByID` needs to take a GUID instead of an int.

Answer (score 8):

> ... use a separate class wrapping up the collection and with methods to add,delete modify data of that collection

This does much more than guarantee the *type* of the objects stored in the collections though, it also guarantees any collection invariants.

Trees (red-black, AVL etc.) are sensitive to ordering and their behaviour depends on rebalancing when appropriate.  Hash table performance will also depend on appropriate re-hashing.  Do you want to remember to check the load factor every time you insert into a hash map?

FWIW, the text is quite clear about this (and I'll edit the whole thing into your question, so no-one else needs to download that RTF):

> Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to the collection have a home

Nothing to do with types (or therefore generics), everything to do with associating the collection's behaviour with it's data.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **"No"** if you are using a language that supports Generics. Because there is no need to check for type as the language feature itself does a pretty good job at this ( From my Java generics experience).

But if You have any situation where you want to customize the data structure given from the language, You can create a wrapper class around the original data structure and expose your own APIs and still use the underlying implementation of the original data structure.

Comment: I am also thinking in the similar lines. but there should be something, the examples I saw for this were in Java and C# and both support generic collections.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: My point was to keep it simple. Unless I don't need to override any specific behavior of the data structure, I will not customize.